# Как лайкнуть репозиторий на github через requests.post?

Tags: python, python-3.x, github, requests

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Или может есть библиотека с такой возможностью ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Звёздочку репозиторию можно поставить с помощью [GitHub REST API v3](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/starring/#star-a-repository):

```
PUT /user/starred/:owner/:repo
```

Есть [много библиотек на Питоне](https://developer.github.com/v3/libraries/), которые оборачивают это API. Легко свою создать:

```
import requests

class Github:
    def __init__(self, token, api_url='https://api.github.com'):
        self.token = token
        self.api_url = api_url
        self.headers = {
            'Accept': 'application/vnd.github.v3+json',
            'Authorization': 'token ' + self.token
        }

    def star(self, repo, owner):
        requests.put(f"{self.api_url}/user/starred/{owner}/{repo}",
                     headers=self.headers).raise_for_status()
```

Пример, чтобы звёздочку [cpython](https://github.com/python/cpython) поставить:

```
import os

github = Github(os.environ['GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN'])
github.star(repo='cpython', owner='python')
```

Чтобы попробовать, можно завести [личный token](https://github.com/settings/tokens). Для приложений, можно [автоматически token создать](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth_authorizations/#create-a-new-authorization).

Answer (score 2):

Прямые запросы к серверу GitHub через *requests* не помогут. Сделано это для [безопасности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) Вам определенно пора узнать что такое API. У гитхаб оно располагается [тут](https://developer.github.com/v3/). А вот не плохой [туториал](https://habrahabr.ru/post/150181/)

Answer (score 1):

[GitHub REST API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721648/23044) использует HTTP PUT (`requests.put`), чтобы добавить звёздочку репозиторию. Чтобы через HTTP POST (`requests.post`) это реализовать, можно использовать [Github GraphQL API v4](https://developer.github.com/v4/reference/mutation/addstar/):

```
data = graphql(
    '''mutation ($starrable_id: ID!) {
addStar(input: {starrableId: $starrable_id}) {
    clientMutationId
    starrable {
      id
      viewerHasStarred
    }
  }
}''',
    starrable_id=repo_id)
```

где `repo_id` необходимо получить ещё одним GraphQL запросом:

```
data = graphql(
    '''query ($repo: String!, $owner: String!) {
  repository(name: $repo, owner: $owner) {
    id
  }
}''',
    repo='cpython',
    owner='python')
repo_id = data['repository']['id']
```

где `graphql()` вызывает `requests.post()`:

```
import os
import requests
def graphql(query, **variables):
    r = requests.post(
        'https://api.github.com/graphql',
        headers={
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + os.environ['GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN']
        },
        json=dict(query=query.replace('\n', ' '), variables=variables))
    r.raise_for_status()
    response = r.json()
    if 'errors' in response:
        raise RuntimeError(response['errors'])
    return response['data']
```

Можно использовать тот же [token](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/), что и [REST API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721648/23044).