# Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?

Tags: javascript, python, python-3.x, парсер, python-faq

Как парсить `html` страничку с `JavaScript` в `python 3` и что для этого нужно.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Чтобы достать *статические* данные из html, javascript текста, можно использовать соответствующие парсеры, такие как BeautifulSoup, slimit. Пример: [Как, используя Beautuful Soup, искать по ключевому слову если это слово находится в теге script?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/705737/23044)

Чтобы получить информацию с web-странички, элементы которой javascript *динамически* генерирует, можно web-браузером воспользоваться. Чтобы управлять разными браузерами из Питона, [selenium webdriver](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html) помогает: [пример с показом GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8960288/4279). Есть и другие библиотеки, к примеру: marionette (firefox), pyppeteer (chrome, puppeteer API для Питона) — [пример получения снимка экрана с web-страницей с использованием этих библиотек](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/821319/23044). Чтобы получить html страницу, не показывая GUI, можно «безголовый» (headless) Google Chrome запустить и с использованием selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver  # $ pip install selenium

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
# get chromedriver from 
# https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)

browser.get('https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943')
# ... other actions
generated_html = browser.page_source
browser.quit()
```

Этот интерфейс позволяет автоматизировать действия пользователя (нажатие клавиш, кнопок, поиск элементов на странице по различным критериям, итд). Анализ полезно на две части разбить: загрузить из сети динамически генерируемую информацию с помощью браузера и сохранить её (возможно наличие избыточной информации), а затем детально анализировать уже статическое содержимое, чтобы изъять только необходимые части (возможно без сети в другом процессе с помощью того же [BeautifulSoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)). К примеру, чтобы найти ссылки на похожие вопросы на сохранённой странице:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(generated_html, 'html.parser')
h = soup.find(id='h-related')
related = [a['href'] for a in h.find_all('a', 'question-hyperlink')]
```

Если сайт предоставляет API (официальное или подсмотренное в сетевых запросах выполняемых javascript: [пример для fifa.com](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/845845/23044)), то это может быть более предпочтительным вариантом по сравнению с выдёргиванием информации c UI элементов web-страницы: [пример, использования Stack Exchange API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/729167/23044).

Часто можно встретить [REST API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721648/23044) или [GraphQL API](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/721721/23044), которые удобно с помощью [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) или специализированных библиотек использовать (по ссылкам примеры кода для github api).