# как авторизоваться на сайте c помощью python?

Tags: python, запрос, авторизация

Пробовала авторизоваться таким образом, чтобы скачать текст с сайта:

```
s = requests.Session()
poem_page = s.post(poems_source, auth=auth.HTTPDigestAuth(login, password))
poem_soup = BeautifulSoup(poem_page.text, 'html.parser')
```

Но не получается и в результате выводит:

```
<div class="post" style="min-width:240px; margin-bottom:35px;">
<form action="auth.php" class="form-inline" method="post" style="margin-bottom:5px">
<table style="max-width:295px">
<tr><td style="min-width:150px; max-width:220px">
<input class="input" maxlength="15" name="login" placeholder="логин" style="min-width:150px" type="text">
<br>
<input class="input" id="input02" maxlength="15" name="password" placeholder="пароль" style="min-width:150px; margin-top:3px" type="password">
</input></br></input></td>
<td style="vertical-align:top;">
<button class="btn btn-primary" style="vertical-align:top; width:70px; margin-top:0px; margin-left:3px" type="submit">Вход</button>
</td></tr>
</table>
</form>
<a class="label" href="./registration.php" style=" margin-right:5px">Регистарция</a>
<a class="label" href="./forgot_pass.php" style=" margin-right:5px">Забыли пароль?</a>
<br>
<div style="margin-top:10px;">или войти через:</div>
<div style="margin-top:10px; margin-bottom:10px">
<script src="//ulogin.ru/js/ulogin.js"></script>
<div data-ulogin="display=panel;theme=flat;fields=first_name,last_name,photo;providers=vkontakte,twitter,google,facebook;hidden=other;redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Fvse-shutochki.ru%2Fauth_soc.php;mobilebuttons=1;" id="uLogin"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Попробуйте это https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/

Comment: это от сайта зависит. Если не хотите разбираться как сайт устроен (подсмотрев какие запросы на сервер посылаются браузером), то просто повторите ручные действия по заходу на сайт в браузере с помощью selenium webdriver и [headless] chrome. [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)

Comment: Без ссылки на сайт и, желательно, тестовых логина/пароля помочь с кодом не выйдет. А так, как выше писали -- через инструмент разработчика посмотреть на запрос на сайт и повторить его в коде