# И снова парсинг сайта на python

Tags: python, парсер

День добрый нужен совет/подсказка, есть сайт "https://hawkbets.com/", но что не пробывал (передовать заголовки и тд) не получается получить "полный" код страницы. body не хочет показывать, ни в какую.
Мб там какая защита или еще что? В какую сторону направиться читать мануалы(силениум пока не хочется использовать)?

Comment: Попробуйте поискать нужное содержимое через `requests.get("https://hawkbets.com/ajax/views/live-series?languageCodeName=en").json()`.

Answer (score 1):

Сайт просто подгружается через js. Чтобы получить всё содержимое, надо либо выполнять тот же запрос, что делает и сайт для получения содержимого, либо использовать selenium

[Python. Парсинг страницы после полной её загрузки(css, js)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/768276/)