# Парсинг динамических данных сайта на python

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, requests, web-scraping

Пытаюсь спарсить страницу букмекерской конторы, проблема в том, что при обычном запросе:

```
import requests

r = requests.get('https://1xstavka.ru/live/Football/125983-Friendlies-National-Teams/155464238-Bulgaria-Bosnia-and-Herzegovina/')
print(r.text)
```

Нужные мне значения приходят в таком виде:

```html
<div class="db-stats-table__group">
  <div class="db-stats-table__count">{{ _doptablo_stat.corners.val1 }}</div>
  <div class="db-stats-table__description">Угловые</div>
  <div class="db-stats-table__count">{{ _doptablo_stat.corners.val2 }}</div>
</div>
```

Я в этом не особо разбираюсь, так что попробовал сделать это с помощью phantomjs:
Ссылки разные, т.к. матчи идут онлайн и все время меняются.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
my_url = 'https://1xstavka.ru/live/Football/28811-UEFA-European-U21-Championship/155474879-Gibraltar-U21-Serbia-U21/'
driver.get(my_url)
print(driver.page_source)
```

Так данные приходят нужные, но на это уходит аж 7 секунд для одной игры, а их там бывает около 50 одновременно, и все нужно проанализировать.

Собственно вопрос, можно ли как-то имитировать эти запросы, которые приходят при использовании requests из двойных фигурных скобок, напрямую, не загружая всю страницу? Или какой-нибудь другой способ, чтобы сделать это быстрее. Заранее спасибо. Оставляю ссылку на сайт, вдруг кому так легче будет отследить.

[Сайт](https://1xstavka.ru/live/Football/)

Comment: то есть у вас вопрос: как ускорить извлечение динамической информации, с сайтов. Не пробовали официальное/неофициальное API поискать? Сразу по 20 игр обрабатывать параллельно? Связанный вопрос: [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)

Comment: api отсутствует. Насчет параллельности не думал я, так можно?

Comment: конечно. Начните с измерений, чтобы узнать где у вас узкое место.

Comment: @karambaq, https://1xst avka.ru/{type}Feed/Get1x2_VZip?sports={sportid}&count={count}&mode=4&getEmpty=true а это что?) докуентацию не нашёл. type - Line или Live . sportid - до 9 вроде. методом подбора можно узнать

Comment: Вы лучше используйте **beautifulsoup** для парсинга страниц. Он очень удобен и легко в понимании.