# Пытаюсь получить информацию через bs4. Выходит ничего. Пустой терминал. Не подскажете что такое?

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautiful-soup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

mortality = 'https://world-statistics.org'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}
print(1)
full_page = requests.get(mortality, headers = headers)
print(2)
soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')
print(3)
convert = soup.findAll("a", {"id": "popclock", "class": "h2" "font-w300" "text-primary" "animated flipInX"})
print(4)
txt = f'Result {convert}'
print(5)
print(txt)
```

Вот сам код HTML:

```
< a id="popclock" class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX">7,804,745,379< /a >
```

Cайт:
https://world-statistics.org/

Answer (score 3):

А вот так всё работает:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

mortality = 'https://world-statistics.org'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/84.0.4147.105 Safari/537.36'}

content = requests.get(mortality, headers=headers).content
# content = '<a id="popclock" class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX">7,804,745,379</a>'

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html.parser')

query = {"id": "popclock", "class": "h2" "font-w300" "text-primary" "animated flipInX"}
convert = soup.findAll("a", query)
print(convert)
```

У вас зачем-то были кавычки в поисковом запросе:

```py
{"id": "popclock", "class": "h2" "font-w300" "text-primary" "animated flipInX"}
```

При этом произошла конкатенация и всё слилось в один большой идентификатор.

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно вы хотите получить число, хранящееся в этой ссылке, но, как я понял, у вас это не получится. Из тех четырёх чисел, что там расположены вы сможете получить только UNDERNOURISHED PEOPLE и CO2 EMISSIONS, так как они у них не динамические, а WORLD POPULATION и GDP (CURRENT US$) обновляются каждую секунду, вероятно при помощи JavaScript. При парсинге они пустые. Вот эти четыре числа с главной страницы:

```
<a class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX" id="popclock"></a>
<a class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX"> 792.50</a>
<a class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX" id="gdpclock"></a>
<a class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX">36,138,285</a>
```

**Коротко говоря, вам нужен Selenium:**
[Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-javascript-%d0%b2-python-3)
[Парсинг динамических данных сайта на python](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/803774/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-python)

Answer (score 0):

Вот так находит нормально:

```
convert = soup.findAll("a", {"id": "popclock", "class": "h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX"})
```

А у вас просто всё слепляется интерпретатором в одну строку без пробелов, такое, конечно, не может там найтись:

```
print("h2" "font-w300" "text-primary" "animated flipInX")
```

Вывод:

```
h2font-w300text-primaryanimated flipInX
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/RCfex5VR . Почему-то вывод такой: [<a class="h2 font-w300 text-primary animated flipInX" id="popclock"></a>]

Comment: @АндрейИванов Ну это то, что есть в коде страницы, там пустой тэг `a`. Вы объясните, что хотите получить.

Comment: На сайте есть строка: `WORLD POPULATION
 NOW
7,804,800,638 # число населения
Based on UN World Prospects, 2019 rev` Мне нужно достать это число. Сайт: https://world-statistics.org/