# python Скриншот веб страницы без запуска диалоговых окон браузера

Tags: python, selenium

К примеру selenium'ом это решается красиво и лаконично, *но при этом открывается окно браузера*. Можно ли как-нибудь делать скриншоты без этого? Возможно, используя другой подход (не через selenium)

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER = "chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(DRIVER)
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("my_screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Используйте headless режимы в Chrome и Firefox, и будет вам радость))) PhantoJS уже всё))

Answer (score 2):

Нашел способ. Просто нужно было использовать [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), с ним окно браузера не открывается .

```
from selenium import webdriver

DRIVER = '\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\\bin\phantomjs.exe'

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(DRIVER) 
driver.get("https://ru.stackoverflow.com/")
screenshot = driver.save_screenshot("my_screenshot.png")
driver.quit()
```

Comment: [PhantomJS Is Dead, Use Chrome Headless in Continuous Integration](https://semaphoreci.com/blog/2018/03/27/phantomjs-is-dead-use-chrome-headless-in-continuous-integration.html)

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ снимок экрана c веб-страницей получить — это запустить браузер с подходящими опциями:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from subprocess import check_call

url = 'https://ru.stackoverflow.com'
width, height = 1920, 1080
filename = "my_screenshot.png"
chrome_executable = 'chromium-browser'
check_call([chrome_executable, '--headless', f'--screenshot={filename}',
            f'--window-size={width},{height}', '--hide-scrollbars',
            url])
```

Аналог для selenium выглядит как:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from selenium import webdriver  # $ pip install selenium

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')
options.add_argument(f'window-size={width},{height}')
options.add_argument('hide-scrollbars')

# get chromedriver from
# https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
browser.get(url)
browser.save_screenshot(filename)
```

Можно напрямую API использовать без selenium, к примеру, у firefox есть marionette:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os
# $ pip install marionette_driver
from marionette_driver.marionette import Marionette

firefox_binary = '/usr/bin/firefox'  # full path
os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
client = Marionette('localhost', bin=firefox_binary, port=2828)
try:
    client.start_session()
    client.set_window_size(width, height)
    client.navigate(url)
    with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
        file.write(client.screenshot(format='binary'))
finally:
    client.quit()
```

Для chrome можно использовать puppeteer или его аналог для Питона [pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import asyncio
import pyppeteer  # $ pip install pyppeteer

async def main():    
    browser = await pyppeteer.launch()
    page = await browser.newPage()
    await page.goto(url)
    await page.setViewport(dict(width=width, height=height))
    await page.screenshot(path=filename, fullPage=False)
    await browser.close()

asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(main())
```

Все представленные варианты только видимую часть сохраняют. При желании можно целиком страницу в виде картинки получить. К примеру, в последнем варианте, достаточно `fullPage=True` указать.