# Авторизация и парсинг python requests

Tags: python, парсер, auth, requests

Пытаюсь авторизоваться на сайте используя `requests`, но не получается. Использую следующий код:

```
s = requests.Session()
data = {'login': 'myLogin', 'password': 'myPass'}
url = "https://studwork.org/login"
r = s.post(url, data=data)
r = s.get("https://studwork.org/mail")
print(r.text)
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Во-первых, отправка формы идёт вообще не на этот адрес. Во-вторых, вы отправляете несуществующие поля `login` и `password`. В-третьих, откройте инструменты разработчика браузера и посмотрите, какой запрос отправляется на самом деле. В-четвёртых, всё это я уже недавно писал.

Comment: По html логин -- `form-login`, пароль -- `form-password`, но отправка формы авторизации перехватывается яваскриптом и заполняется значениями из вопроса: https://studwork.org/jscript/login.js Больший вопрос вызывает функция `AjaxRequest` и `secret_hash_header`. Все-таки проще посмотреть через инструменты разработчика на запрос и повторить. Или использовать селениум -- тогда не понадобится заполнять запросы

Comment: @andreymal: *"всё это я уже недавно писал"* -- просто проголосуйте за закрытие вопроса как дубликата, чтобы в одном месте хороший ответ был (не нужно без нужды повторяться).

Comment: Ой, дубликат не удалён, оказывается. Только вот отметить как дубликат не дают, а ответ я писать не хочу: [Авторизация и парсинг](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/846202)

Comment: @andreymal: чтобы не было необходимости по комментариям разбрасывать мудрость, можно один раз ответ написать для такого типа вопросов, чтобы авторы последующих вопросов могли бы сузить проблему для их конкретного случая (где-то `auth=(login, password)` работает, где-то достаточно простую html форму эмулировать (конкретный адрес, имена разные на разных сайтах могут быть), где-то в http заголовке токен нужно передать и/или другие заголовки такие как User-Agent, где-то javascript выполняется и можно подсмотреть какие запросы он выполняет, где-то браузер придётся запустить (headless chrome)

Comment: в общем создать аналог ответа (только конкретно по заходу на сайты):  [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044) и если автор явно не продемонстрировал результаты общих шагов,  указанных в этом ответе, то закрыть как дубликат, пока более уникальная специфичная информация в вопросе не появится.