# Парсинг динамической таблицы из html на Python

Tags: javascript, python, парсер

Имеем вот такую таблицу:

```
<div id="technicalstudiesSubTabs">
   <ul class="tabsBoxSubMenu techStudiesTabsSubMenu  innerPage " id="timePeriodsWidget"  data-view="normal">
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="60" class="first"><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 мин</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="300" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">5 мин</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="900" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">15 мин</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="1800" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">30 мин</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="3600" class="selected "><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 час</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="18000" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">5 часов</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="86400" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 день</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="week" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 неделя</a></li>
            <li pairid="1031044" data-period="month" class=""><a href="javascript:void(0);">1 месяц</a></li>
       </ul>
</div>
    <div class="align_center displayNone" id="loadingSpinner">
        <img src="https://i-invdn-com.akamaized.net/images/ajax-loader-big.gif">
    </div>
    <div id="techinalContent">
    <div class="newTechStudiesRight instrumentTechTab" id="techStudiesInnerWrap">
        <div class="summary">Резюме:<span class="neutral uppercaseText" title="">Нейтрально</span></div>
        <div class="summaryTableLine"><span>Скол. средние:</span><span
                class="greenFont bold">Покупать</span><span><i
                    class="noBold">Покупать</i> <i id="maBuy">(7)</i></span><span><i
                    class="noBold">Продавать</i> <i id="maSell">(5)</i></span></div>
        <div class="summaryTableLine"><span>Тех. индикаторы:</span><span
                class="redFont bold">Продавать</span><span><i
                    class="noBold">Покупать</i> <i id="tiBuy">(3)</i></span><span><i
                    class="noBold">Продавать</i> <i id="tiSell">(5)</i></span></div>
    </div>
```

Успешно парсится только data-period="3600", который установлен по умолчанию, нужно спарсить все периоды. Таблица формируется при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку. Прошу помощи в решении проблемы.

Comment: а где сам парсер, который парсит только `data-period="3600"`? В парсинге данной страницы никакой проблемы нет, она может быть в конкретном парсере, которого у нас нет.

Comment: `Таблица формируется при нажатии на соответствующую кнопку.` в браузере нажмите на F12 и на вкладке Сети посмотрите происходят ли запросы при клике на ту кнопку

Comment: @gil9red, благодарю! ваш ответ очень помог решить задачу! Действительно, делается запрос ПОСТ, с параметрами и хедерс, указание которых помогло получить ответ. Еще раз спасибо!

Comment: @ДмитрийАрсланов, а вы молодец, сами разобрались :)

Comment: связанный вопрос [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/749943/23044)

Comment: @gil9red спасибо! учитывая что я финансист по образованию, а программирование учил в школе 20(!!!) лет назад, то, наверное, да )) Еще раз спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

В Хроме F12 -> вкладка Networks помогла отловить запрос с Headers и параметрами, повторение которого позволяет получить необходимую информацию.

Comment: @jfs, поправил!