# Рендеринг JS кода на веб-страце при парсинге

Tags: javascript, python, парсер, бот

Страница которую нужно спарсить динамически создаётся через JavaScript.

Посоветуйте простую в освоении python библиотеку способную ренедерить JavaScript код страницы. Использую vps сервер на linux.

Comment: Но зачем? Эти скрипты скорее всего просто скачивают json-файлы с сервера, а уж распарсить json на питоне вообще не проблема, модуль json в него встроен

Comment: @andreymal возможно. Вот страница с которой нужно спарсить таблицу которую генерирует js код: https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/02/the-latest-coronavirus-cases/

Comment: С помощью selenium. https://habr.com/ru/post/248559/

Comment: @СергейАндреев эта таблица — всего лишь фрейм на [гугл-документ](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/e/2PACX-1vR30F8lYP3jG7YOq8es0PBpJIE5yvRVZffOyaqC0GgMBN6yt0Q-NI8pxS7hd1F9dYXnowSC6zpZmW9D/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0), никаких скриптов для создания там вообще не используется

Comment: @Alioshca Z Можно ли настроить Selenium на vps сервере? Selenium же управляет браузером насколько я понимаю.

Comment: @СергейАндреев ничто не мешает запустить браузер на сервере (но в этом нет необходимости, потому что гугл-документ прекрасно читается и без браузера)

Comment: @andreymal я знаю, что это фрейм с гугл-доков. Но на странице гугл-доков генерация также происходит через js

Comment: @СергейАндреев это неправда, я заглядывал в код страницы и проверял с отключенным javascript — таблица есть прямо в html-коде готовенькая без всяких скриптов.

Comment: @andreymal сейчас перепроверю

Comment: @andreymal Вот ссылка на таблицу: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR30F8lYP3jG7YOq8es0PBpJIE5yvRVZffOyaqC0GgMBN6yt0Q-NI8pxS7hd1F9dYXnowSC6zpZmW9D/pubhtml?gid=0&single=true&widget=true&headers=false (для исключения недопонимания). В исходном коде (использую мазилу) каких-либо элементов таблицы нет

Comment: @СергейАндреев на странице, ссылку на которую вы дали в этом комментарии, есть фрейм. Откройте html-код этого фрейма, и там вы увидите таблицу

Comment: @andreymal Действительно, там есть iframe. Перешёл по его ссылке вот сюда: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vR30F8lYP3jG7YOq8es0PBpJIE5yvRVZffOyaqC0GgMBN6yt0Q-NI8pxS7hd1F9dYXnowSC6zpZmW9D/pubhtml/sheet?headers=false&gid=0 Там всё ещё нет таблице в коде.

Comment: @СергейАндреев неправда, там есть таблица в коде. Откройте код, запустите поиск и наберите `<table` — сразу увидите

Comment: @andreymal всё, увидел. Но это всё таки единичный случай. Выше писали о том, что Selenium можно запустить на севере. Действительно ли это так? Будут ли какие-либо проблемы?

Comment: @СергейАндреев с тех пор, в как в Firefox и Chrome добавили headless-режим, проблем больше нет

Comment: @andreymal отлично. Добавьте свой ответ на вопрос. Отмечу его

Comment: А это всё равно дубликат вопроса [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749943)

Comment: @andreymal сейчас воспользовался hedless FireFox через Selenium. Думал, что это решит проблему с парсингом, но нет, html который выдаёт Selenium по-прежнему состоит только из ссылок на скрипты, а не из результата их выполнения. В результате BeautifulSoup всё также не может обрабатывать созданные js элементы страницы. Или я что-то делаю не так?

Comment: @andreymal код: from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
options = Options()
options.headless = True
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get("https://bnonews.com/index.php/2020/02/the-latest-coronavirus-cases/")
generated_html = driver.page_source
page_html = BeautifulSoup(generated_html, "html.parser")
page_html.select(".s23")[1].text
driver.quit()

Comment: @СергейАндреев так вы открывайте вашу предыдущую ссылку из комментария — ту, в которой вы код всё-таки увидели, а не эту. А если вам прям очень-очень хочется именно эту ссылку, ну тогда через selenium ищите элемент с фреймом, открывайте его, в нём ещё раз ищите элемент с фреймом и снова открывайте его, чтобы получить код

Comment: @andreymal всё, теперь разобрался. Спасибо Вам