# Извлечь переменную из скрипта на сайте

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup

На сайте есть блок скриптов

```
  <script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var obj = {
        "title": "Short Sweatshirt",
        "price": "$24.99",
        "description": "Short sweatshirt with long sleeves and ribbing at neckline, cuffs, and hem. 57% cotton, 43% polyester. Machine wash cold.",
        "img_path": "/static/img/" + "96230-C" + ".jpg"
      };

      var cardTitle = document.querySelector(".card-title");
      var cardPrice = document.querySelector(".card-price");
      var cardDescription = document.querySelector(".card-description");
      var cardImg = document.querySelector("img.card-img-top");

      cardTitle.innerHTML = obj.title;
      cardPrice.innerHTML = obj.price;
      cardDescription.innerHTML = obj.description;
      cardImg.setAttribute('src', obj.img_path);
    });

  </script>
```

Мне нужно каким-то образом вытащить из этого блока obj, но вот не понимаю как это сделать. Знаю у requests.get есть параметр .json(), который решает проблему в иных случаях, но я сам блок скрипта вытаскиваю через bs4. Что в таком случае можно сделать?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как парсить html страничку с JavaScript в python 3?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/749943/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d1%81%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81-javascript-%d0%b2-python-3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
txt = '''<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
      var obj = {
        "title": "Short Sweatshirt",
        "price": "$24.99",
        "description": "Short sweatshirt with long sleeves and ribbing at neckline, cuffs, and hem. 57% cotton, 43% polyester. Machine wash cold.",
        "img_path": "/static/img/" + "96230-C" + ".jpg"
      };

      var cardTitle = document.querySelector(".card-title");
      var cardPrice = document.querySelector(".card-price");
      var cardDescription = document.querySelector(".card-description");
      var cardImg = document.querySelector("img.card-img-top");

      cardTitle.innerHTML = obj.title;
      cardPrice.innerHTML = obj.price;
      cardDescription.innerHTML = obj.description;
      cardImg.setAttribute('src', obj.img_path);
    });

  </script>'''

qqq = txt.find('var obj = {')
aaa = eval(txt[qqq+10:txt.find('}')+1])
print(aaa['title'])
print(aaa['price'])
print(aaa['img_path'])

# Short Sweatshirt
# $24.99
# /static/img/96230-C.jpg
```

Comment: Может лучше всё-таки `json.loads`? `eval` без крайней нужды лучше не использовать.

Comment: Вариант с `json.load` мне понравился, и я в нём немного разобрался, но он не работает из-за элемента `img_path` на конкатенации строк в его значении по неизвестной мне причине выдаёт ошибку. Что с этим можно сделать?

Comment: @dnocoder А, да, это засада. Ну, можно наколхозить предварительную замену строки `" + "` на пустую строку. Лучше через регулярки. Но всё-равно, конечно, решение не очень универсальное будет.